# Python error "tries = 1"

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I decided to make a simple program but whenever I try to run it, it gives me a syntax error and highlights "tries = 1" in red. I don't understand why is it doing so?

Here is the code:

```
print("A chance to in a jack\"ass\"pot! Enter a number between 1 and 10!"
tries = 1
while 1:
  if tries == 3:
     print("You lose!")
     break
  val = input("Enter the number: ")
  if val == 7:
     print("Well done! You win $10 million of fake currency")
     break
  else:
     print("Try again loser")
     tries += 1

input("Press enter to continue...")
```

Comment: There's no closing `)` on your print statement.

Comment: Oh, so stupid of me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close the `print()` call:

```
print("A chance to in a jack\"ass\"pot! Enter a number between 1 and 10!"
#   -^ opens but ----------------------------------------- no closing ---^
```

When you don't close the parenthesis, Python sees the next line as part of the statement, and a string followed by `tries` makes no sense.

Rule of thumb: whenever you have an unexplained syntax error, check the preceding lines to see if you have the right number of closing parenthesis, brackets or braces to close all opening braces, brackets and parenthesis.

Note that `input()` in Python 3 returns a string, not an integer, so the comparisons are going to fail:

```
if val == 7:
```

because `val` is a string. Either compare against strings:

```
if val == '7':
```

or convert `val` to an integer:

```
val = int(input("Enter the number: "))
```

Comment: There is another problem. Even if I enter 7, it still prints out "Try again loser."... What is going on there? Even if I use elif, it just highlights it and says "Syntax Error"

Answer (score 0):

You first print:

```
print("A chance to in a jack\"ass\"pot! Enter a number between 1 and 10!"
```

is lagging a closing ).